# Does the Italian mafia account for 7% of Italy's GDP?

Tags: italy

Found it somewhere (which means I forgot where it was) and decided to ask about it here.

Does the Italian mafia account for 7% of Italy's GDP?

Comment: It would be helpful to know if this is strictly illegal business (drug trade), legal busines done in an illegal way (counterfeiting olive oil) or legal businesses the mafia also own (construction)

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that (totally unrelated to the Mafia), the so-called "black" or "irregular" or "cash" economy in Italy (as most Euro countries) is absolutely huge.  You can google studies on this yourself, claims or 40% are common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible.

http://mobile.nytimes.com/2007/10/22/world/europe/22iht-italy.4.8001812.html

> Mafia crime is 7% of GDP in Italy, group reports

[Original report](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.sosimpresa.it/userFiles/File/Documenti6/13_06_2012_audizione_in_commissione_antimafia.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi7zpLy1_TNAhVGbB4KHYdnDVwQFgggMAE&usg=AFQjCNE8YWDDaax0l4WLXwQpLodzOEDqTw&sig2=-aavJ4JmfqfqNLTP6ny_TA)

The source is SOS Impresa, an association that supports businesses threatened by the Mafia. Thus they have a vested interest in inflating the number.

It's highly doubtful that there are meaningful statistics on a criminal organization that seeks to conceal it's activities. The SOS Impresa source is the most recent attempt at this.